# iOS Swift Chart with combine chart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I am using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to achieve this. I am using combine chart for this.

[image]

And I have achieved below things two major problems in this.

1. Line chart scrolls down, how can I disable it?
2. I want to add lines followed by chart
3. How can I select default highlighted value programmatically?

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you, If not please provide further details about the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
combinedChart.zoom(scaleX: 1.0, scaleY: 1.0, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```

2.Use one or more of the following:

```
    combinedChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    combinedChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    combinedChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    combinedChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    combinedChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    combinedChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
```

3.

```
combinedChart.highlightValue(x: 0, dataSetIndex: 0)
```